# How to reformat the json output for column chart?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

Previously I draw a google chart (Pie Chart), using Ajax and the chart can be displayed as it only involved 2 columns.

Now, I want to draw a column chart like this one.

[image: column chart]

This is my SQL Query:

```
$sql = "Select count(application_id) as count, application_status,   category_group from mdl_local_jobs_application 
inner join mdl_local_jobs_job on mdl_local_jobs_application.application_jobid = mdl_local_jobs_job.job_id
left join mdl_local_jobs_category on mdl_local_jobs_job.job_categoryid = mdl_local_jobs_category.category_id 
left join mdl_cohort_members on mdl_local_jobs_application.application_applicantid = mdl_cohort_members.userid
left join mdl_local_cohortrole on mdl_cohort_members.cohortid = mdl_local_cohortrole.cohortid
left join mdl_role on mdl_local_cohortrole.roleid = mdl_role.id where shortname = 'graduates'
group by application_status, category_group";
```

The query is coded into Json output using this:

```
$result_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$row_num = 0;

//loop fetching the query into json format
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$row_num++;
if ($row_num == $result_rows){
  echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $result['application_status'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $result['category_group'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $result['count'] . ",\"f\":null}]}";
} else {
   echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $result['application_status'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $result['category_group'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $result['count'] . ",\"f\":null}]}";
}
}


echo " ] }";
```

This is the output:

```
{ "cols": [ {"id":"","label":"STATUS","pattern":"","type":"string"}, {"id":"","label":"CATEOGRY","pattern":"","type":"string"}, {"id":"","label":"TOTAL","pattern":"","type":"number"} ], "rows": [ {"c":[{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"Accounting/Finance","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}{"c":[{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"Engineering","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]} ] }
```

However, this output cannot be read by google chart. This is the error.

```
Error: Invalid JSON string: { "cols": [ {"id":"","label":"STATUS","pattern":"","type":"string"}, {"id":"","label":"CATEOGRY","pattern":"","type":"string"}, {"id":"","label":"TOTAL","pattern":"","type":"number"} ], "rows": [ {"c":[{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"Accounting/Finance","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}{"c":[{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":"Engineering","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]} ] }
```

My question: How I want to reformat the code to get the output for the column chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to add a comma to the end of each row...

```
if ($row_num == $result_rows){
  echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $result['application_status'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $result['category_group'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $result['count'] . ",\"f\":null}]},"; // <-- add comma
} else {
  echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $result['application_status'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $result['category_group'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $result['count'] . ",\"f\":null}]},"; // <-- add comma
}
```

Comment: Thanks @WHiteHat. Your answer solved half of my problem. The error gone as the json string is in the right format. I don't know why the format difference in comma for column chart but pie chart no need to have comma. Only that, the chart cannot display correctly although i made changes on the label type. I have put another question here,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46083389/how-to-make-sql-query-to-get-the-sum-of-specific-column... if you mind to help and share your knowledge..thanks for your contribution in helping me solving the problem. I already accept your answer.