# How to make SQL Query to get the sum of specific column?

Tags: mysql, charts

Previously I draw a google chart (Pie Chart), using Ajax and the chart can be displayed as it only involved 2 columns.

Now, I want to draw a column chart like this one.

[image: column chart]

This is my SQL Query:

```
$sql = "Select count(application_id) as count, application_status,   category_group from mdl_local_jobs_application 
inner join mdl_local_jobs_job on mdl_local_jobs_application.application_jobid = mdl_local_jobs_job.job_id
left join mdl_local_jobs_category on mdl_local_jobs_job.job_categoryid = mdl_local_jobs_category.category_id 
left join mdl_cohort_members on mdl_local_jobs_application.application_applicantid = mdl_cohort_members.userid
left join mdl_local_cohortrole on mdl_cohort_members.cohortid = mdl_local_cohortrole.cohortid
left join mdl_role on mdl_local_cohortrole.roleid = mdl_role.id where shortname = 'graduates'
group by application_status, category_group";
```

The query is coded into Json output using this:

```
$result_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$row_num = 0;

//loop fetching the query into json format
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$row_num++;
if ($row_num == $result_rows){
   echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $result['category_group'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $result['application_status'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $result['count'] . ",\"f\":null}]},";
} else {
   echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $result['category_group'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $result['application_status'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":" . $result['count'] . ",\"f\":null}]},";
}
}


echo " ] }";
```

This is the output:

```
{ "cols": [ {"id":"","label":"CATEOGRY","pattern":"","type":"string"}, {"id":"","label":"CATEOGRY","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"TOTAL","pattern":"","type":"number"} ], "rows": [ {"c":[{"v":"Accounting/Finance","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Engineering","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]}, ] }
```

However, the chart don't display correctly because the value of application status is not a number. I do read on the other solutions to get the result by sum function in sql but I do not know how to do it.

My question: How I want to do SQL Query to get the total count of each application status (0,1,2--status type)

My expected output is to be like this:

```
{ "cols": [ {"id":"","label":"CATEOGRY","pattern":"","type":"string"}, {"id":"","label":"CATEOGRY","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"TOTAL","pattern":"","type":"number"} ], "rows": [ {"c":[{"v":"Accounting/Finance","f":null},{"v":4,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Engineering","f":null},{"v":7,"f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]}, ] }
```

The difference is in the second array value, I want to have the value by making SQL Query (using sum function) to get calculated sum for each status that are 0 status, 1 status, and 2 status.

```
{"c":[{"v":"Accounting/Finance","f":null},{"v":4,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},
```

If I make this Query(changes in where statement, I can only get the count of status "0" only. How I want to add another where statement in the same query to get the count of other status, status "1" and status "2"?

```
$sql = "Select count(application_id) as count, category_group from mdl_local_jobs_application 
 inner join mdl_local_jobs_job on mdl_local_jobs_application.application_jobid = mdl_local_jobs_job.job_id
 left join mdl_local_jobs_category on mdl_local_jobs_job.job_categoryid = mdl_local_jobs_category.category_id 
 left join mdl_cohort_members on mdl_local_jobs_application.application_applicantid = mdl_cohort_members.userid
 left join mdl_local_cohortrole on mdl_cohort_members.cohortid = mdl_local_cohortrole.cohortid
 left join mdl_role on mdl_local_cohortrole.roleid = mdl_role.id where shortname = 'graduates' and application_status = 0
 group by category_group";
```

Comment: can you add expected output? I cant get what is your problem

Comment: Don't you already get it with `count`?

Comment: I already edit my question for your better understanding. @Oleg, the count is the total application for each category but it is duplicating the status "0".--> {"v":"Accounting/Finance","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Engineering","f":null},{"v":"0","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]}

Comment: So why do you do `\"" . $result['application_status'] . "\",` then ? you need to avoid double quetes so just `" . $result['application_status'] . ",`

Comment: Thanks, but sorry my understanding is still not good enough. Where did the `4` came from? Why are you doing the same thing in `if/else`? I do understand enough to guess what you want, so if I guessed correctly you need to do `count(application_id) * application_status as count`.

Comment: @Alex, I just edit my question for your understanding. Sorry for hard to deliver a better question. Thanks for your correction on double quote...duplicating mistakenly.

Comment: @OLeg, the 4 is just a sample result for your understanding, it is harcoded. I do edit my question. Yes, I want to make count for each status in the SQL Query.

Comment: If the query at the end of your answer does what you want for `0` status then your original query already does what you want for all statuses.

Comment: To get good answer you should provide us your data tables structure and samples of data in those tables that illustrate your case. Then we need to see your current query result and your expected results. The best way to provide such info is to set up sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this SQL Query:

```
$sql = "Select count(application_id) as count, sum(case when application_status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) PendingCount, sum(case when application_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) RejectedCount, sum(case when application_status = 2 then 1 else 0 end)SuccessCount, category_group from mdl_local_jobs_application
inner join mdl_local_jobs_job on mdl_local_jobs_application.application_jobid = mdl_local_jobs_job.job_id
left join mdl_local_jobs_category on mdl_local_jobs_job.job_categoryid = mdl_local_jobs_category.category_id 
left join mdl_cohort_members on mdl_local_jobs_application.application_applicantid = mdl_cohort_members.userid
left join mdl_local_cohortrole on mdl_cohort_members.cohortid = mdl_local_cohortrole.cohortid
left join mdl_role on mdl_local_cohortrole.roleid = mdl_role.id where shortname = 'graduates'
group by category_group";
```

This is the output:

```
{ "cols": [ {"id":"","label":"CATEOGRY","pattern":"","type":"string"}, {"id":"","label":"PENDING","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"REJECTED","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"SUCCESS","pattern":"","type":"number"}, {"id":"","label":"TOTAL","pattern":"","type":"number"} ], "rows": [ {"c":[{"v":"Accounting/Finance","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null},{"v":0,"f":null}, {"v":0,"f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Engineering","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null},{"v":0,"f":null}, {"v":0,"f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]}, ] }
```

The chart can appear according to the status type..

Anyway, thank you @Alex, @Oleg for your comment and sharing to get me out from the problem. I'm sorry for getting you into puzzle with my problem.